# Strange IP on auto ServerName - Apache2 restart

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ip

I'm not sure what to search for on google for this, but something strange happened when I restarted apache2. I'm using an ubuntu server, 11.04, and got this message

> apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified
>   domain name, using 207.223.0.140 for ServerName

A strange IP, not even close to the one I have. Could it be someone changed this? Is there a way to change it back to 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normaly those errors have to do with your configured ServerName and the hosts-file.

Make sure you have an entry for localhost and one for the chosen ServerName in your /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1         localhost
999.999.999.999   example.com
```

Make sure to set your IP instead of 999.999... and your hostname instead of example.com ;)

For further information google for "Apache2 could not reliably determine". You'll find something for sure.

Comment: Well what I'm asking is why it's 207.223.0.140. Just seems like a random ip for it to set to.

Comment: OK, two things come to mind: 1 ) If your running the Server behind a router or a NAT, you could check if this is your public IP (goto http://www.formyip.com/ or see [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/to-find-the-public-ip-on-ubuntu-server-8-10-a-692809/) for commands to do the same).
2 ) Could your ServerName or the ServerName in Combination with the search domain in /etc/resolv.conf resolve to this IP?

Comment: One more thing that might be interesting is how apache does the lookups to determine the IP:
First it tries a DNS-Lookup on the global ServerName.
If that fails it will take the systems hostname (type hostname in console) and do a lookup on that.
I don't know what it does if none of those resolve correctly though.
The according part of the documentation can be found [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/dns-caveats.html#main)

Comment: It's not my public ip, but I just did a whois look up (should've done that in the first place) based on your idea and it seems to be one of my ISPs DNS servers. I think that's it then. Strange that ubuntu would pick that ip though

Comment: Also I think your latest comment answers the question, but it was the fact my /etc/hosts file wasn't correct, so I'll mark your answer correct